# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}} dx$ for polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of degree $2n-1$ and $2n$ respectively.

Tags: integration, polynomials, definite-integrals

Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{g(x)}} dx$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $(2n-1)$ and $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ (Both polynomials with integer coefficients).
This is quite easy for $n=1$ but my problem deals with $n=5$. 
So, I wanted to obtain a generalized solution for any integer n > 0.

How should I approach? Thanks.

**Edit1**: And as for the relationship between the polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, you can think of it as $f(x)=A(x)A′(x)+B(x)B′(x)$ and $g(x)=A(x)^{2}+B(x)^{2}$ where $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are polynomials of order $n$.

Comment: Did you solve the case $n=3$.

Comment: I don't see how you'd do this in general. Perhaps the one you did had particular characteristics that made it possible. I can't see a way to do it in general. However, it's easy to see that you can always do this whenever $f(x)=g'(x).$ Also, the case when $g(x)$ is a perfect square is doable in theory. I can't see any other general cases, unless one sees a specific relationship between the two polynomials.

Comment: No, I didn't @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: @Allawonder I agree that the two cases you mentioned can be solved. But, I am having this integral with $n=5$, I also could not find any such method. And as for the relationship between two polynomials, you can think of it as $f(x) = A(x)A'(x) + B(x)B'(x)$ and $g(x) = A(x)^{2} + B(x)^{2}$ where $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are polynomials of order $n$.

Comment: @UTKARSHAASHUMISHRA I think it's better to post the *specific* problem you're dealing with. After all, what hope do you have that generalising it in this way will simplify the solution?

Comment: Note that for the specific form of $f, g$ you gave in the comments, $f = \frac{1}{2} g'$, which suggests the substitution $u = \,$...